# How do I get Samba to use a specific domain controller?

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, rodc

Currently, I have Samba on Ubunut Linux 16.04 connecting to a domain controller.  When I joined, I joined to `ad-1.example.com`; however, after two weeks, it found `read-only-adc.example.com` on its own subnet and proceeded to completely fail to function anymore.

Samba really, *really* doesn't like read-only domain controllers.

Thus far, I haven't found any way to force Samba to use the primary domain controller one subnet over, either by modifying `/etc/krb.conf` or putting false information in `/etc/hosts` (it finds the IP address without looking in the `hosts` file).

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Put fully functional controllers to the */etc/krb.conf*, add a `password server = <name of the fully functional controller>` to your *smb.conf* and rejoin samba to your domain, since samba actually keeps a copy of your *krb.conf* somewehere inside */var* (this differs from distribution to distribution). Also, the step with the `password server` and actual */etc/krb.conf* may be enough for itself.

Comment: I hadn't sufficiently read the documentation, and don't understand AD and LDAP very well.  Reading the `password server` documentation within the context of this answer suddenly makes plenty of sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can just use a hosts entry to accomplish this. Just point example.com to that one domain controller. I'm not sure if you would need to invalidate read-only with a fake IP in the hosts file also, but you could try it if it keeps going back there.

Comment: It ignores /etc/hosts entries because it looks up via `lmhosts` and WINS first.  You can change this around with `name resolve order`.