# Windows domain joined Linux server tries to authenticate to multiple AD controllers

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, domain-controller, kerberos

i have set up a Debian Server and let i join our domain.

Our company has multiple domain controllers around europe.

I have installed Winbind, Samba, Kerberos5, PAM and Open SSL on this machine.
After the domain join i noticed that this machine tires to authenticate to every domain controller in our domain with ldap and kerberos, which causes extremly long wait times before we can log in via ssh.

Is there a way to force Debian to only authenticate with the domain controller on our site?

Comment: could you provide some informations about how to join the Debian server to the windows domain?

Comment: You mean like my the configuration i use? I can post this in about 1 hour. The documentation i used for it was from https://www.sysadminblog.at/?p=186

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the site structure set up correctly? you can check this using 'Active Directory Sites and Services' on any DC.

Make sure you have a site for each location that has one or more DCs and make sure each DC is in the correct site.

Then create subnets for all IP ranges in use and assign each subnet to their site or the closest (=shortest latency) site.

This should force your Debian servers to use the closest DC instead of trying to authenticate to all of them

Comment: Our network is set up that way but the Debian server still tries to authenticate with every other server. Is there no way to tell winbind or kerberos to only use a specific domaincontroller?

Comment: I can't test this at the moment since I don't have an environment with AD domain joined Linux servers, but I did find an answer right here in [StackExchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/838988/how-do-i-get-samba-to-use-a-specific-domain-controller)